# DPDK: Error While compiling the sample application on Windows

Tags: windows, dpdk

I am trying [Compiling the DPDK Target from Source](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/windows_gsg/build_dpdk.html) on Windows.

When I run the following Command

```
ninja -C build
```

The following errors are shown:

```
ninja: Entering directory `build'
[7/695] Compiling C object lib/librte_cryptodev.a.p/cryptodev_rte_cryptodev.c.obj
FAILED: lib/librte_cryptodev.a.p/cryptodev_rte_cryptodev.c.obj
"clang" "-Ilib\librte_cryptodev.a.p" "-Ilib" "-I..\lib" "-Ilib\cryptodev" "-I..\lib\cryptodev" "-I." "-I.." "-Iconfig" "-I..\config" "-Ilib\eal\include" "-I..\lib\eal\include" "-Ilib\eal\windows\include" "-I..\lib\eal\windows\include" "-Ilib\eal\x86\include" "-I..\lib\eal\x86\include" "-Ilib\eal\common" "-I..\lib\eal\common" "-Ilib\eal" "-I..\lib\eal" "-Ilib\kvargs" "-I..\lib\kvargs" "-Ilib\mbuf" "-I..\lib\mbuf" "-Ilib\mempool" "-I..\lib\mempool" "-Ilib\ring" "-I..\lib\ring" "-Ilib\metrics" "-I..\lib\metrics" "-Ilib\telemetry" "-I..\lib\telemetry" "-Ilib\rcu" "-I..\lib\rcu" "-Xclang" "-fcolor-diagnostics" "-pipe" "-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64" "-Wall" "-Winvalid-pch" "-Wextra" "-O3" "-include" "rte_config.h" "-Wcast-qual" "-Wdeprecated" "-Wformat" "-Wformat-nonliteral" "-Wformat-security" "-Wmissing-declarations" "-Wmissing-prototypes" "-Wnested-externs" "-Wold-style-definition" "-Wpointer-arith" "-Wsign-compare" "-Wstrict-prototypes" "-Wundef" "-Wwrite-strings" "-Wno-address-of-packed-member" "-Wno-missing-field-initializers" "-D_GNU_SOURCE" "-D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0A00" "-D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS" "-march=native" "-DALLOW_EXPERIMENTAL_API" "-DALLOW_INTERNAL_API" "-DRTE_LOG_DEFAULT_LOGTYPE=lib.cryptodev" -MD -MQ lib/librte_cryptodev.a.p/cryptodev_rte_cryptodev.c.obj -MF "lib\librte_cryptodev.a.p\cryptodev_rte_cryptodev.c.obj.d" -o lib/librte_cryptodev.a.p/cryptodev_rte_cryptodev.c.obj "-c" ../lib/cryptodev/rte_cryptodev.c
In file included from ../lib/cryptodev/rte_cryptodev.c:18:
In file included from ..\lib\eal\x86\include\rte_memcpy.h:17:
In file included from ..\lib\eal\x86\include\rte_vect.h:26:
In file included from C:\Program Files\LLVM\lib\clang\7.0.1\include\immintrin.h:203:
C:\Program Files\LLVM\lib\clang\7.0.1\include\vaesintrin.h:45:19: error: unknown type name '__m512i'
static __inline__ __m512i __DEFAULT_FN_ATTRS_F
                  ^
C:\Program Files\LLVM\lib\clang\7.0.1\include\vaesintrin.h:45:27: error: expected identifier or '('
static __inline__ __m512i __DEFAULT_FN_ATTRS_F
                          ^
C:\Program Files\LLVM\lib\clang\7.0.1\include\vaesintrin.h:35:30: note: expanded from macro '__DEFAULT_FN_ATTRS_F'
#define __DEFAULT_FN_ATTRS_F __attribute__((__always_inline__, __nodebug__, __target__("avx512f,vaes"), __min_vector_width__(512)))
                             ^
C:\Program Files\LLVM\lib\clang\7.0.1\include\vaesintrin.h:59:19: error: unknown type name '__m512i'
static __inline__ __m512i __DEFAULT_FN_ATTRS_F
                  ^
C:\Program Files\LLVM\lib\clang\7.0.1\include\vaesintrin.h:59:27: error: expected identifier or '('
static __inline__ __m512i __DEFAULT_FN_ATTRS_F
                          ^
C:\Program Files\LLVM\lib\clang\7.0.1\include\vaesintrin.h:35:30: note: expanded from macro '__DEFAULT_FN_ATTRS_F'
#define __DEFAULT_FN_ATTRS_F __attribute__((__always_inline__, __nodebug__, __target__("avx512f,vaes"), __min_vector_width__(512)))
                             ^
C:\Program Files\LLVM\lib\clang\7.0.1\include\vaesintrin.h:73:19: error: unknown type name '__m512i'
static __inline__ __m512i __DEFAULT_FN_ATTRS_F
                  ^
C:\Program Files\LLVM\lib\clang\7.0.1\include\vaesintrin.h:73:27: error: expected identifier or '('
static __inline__ __m512i __DEFAULT_FN_ATTRS_F
                          ^
C:\Program Files\LLVM\lib\clang\7.0.1\include\vaesintrin.h:35:30: note: expanded from macro '__DEFAULT_FN_ATTRS_F'
#define __DEFAULT_FN_ATTRS_F __attribute__((__always_inline__, __nodebug__, __target__("avx512f,vaes"), __min_vector_width__(512)))
                             ^
```

I don't know what is the problem exactly.